# jquery: adding effect to changing contents of a selected element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-effects

I am trying to add an animation effect to changing contents of a selected element.

Like here's my code to change contents of a div..

```
$('.message').html('The product has been deleted.');
```

I want to add a simple slide down effect to this process. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#check').click(function() {

    $('.text').html('Here is my text.').hide().slideDown('slow'); // don't forget to hide it first....

});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/pxKnM/)

Answer (score 2):

Just call `$('.message').html('The product has been deleted.').hide().slideDown();`
(http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working http://jsfiddle.net/YmDeq/ - I want that the text should appear sliding down. Its just popping up in this case.

Comment: Sorry - forgot the "hide()" call (just noticed Reigel has this below already).